# How do you make an NSTextField in a custom View be the first responder?

Tags: cocoa, xcode6

It's my understanding that making the textfield the ***first responder*** means that you can enter text into the textfield without having to click on the textfield first.

I made a simple app to demonstrate the problem.  Here are the files:

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  MyFirstResponderApp
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MyViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property(strong) MyViewController* viewCtrl;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    MyViewController* myViewCtrl = [[MyViewController alloc]
                                   initWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:nil];

    [self setViewCtrl:myViewCtrl];

    [[self window] setContentSize:[[myViewCtrl view] bounds].size];
    [[self window] setContentView:[myViewCtrl view]];



}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}

@end
```

...

```
//
//  MyViewController.h
//  MyFirstResponderApp
//

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface MyViewController : NSViewController

@property IBOutlet NSTextField* textField;

@end
```

...

```
//
//  MyViewController.m
//  MyFirstResponderApp
//

#import "MyViewController.h"

@interface MyViewController ()

@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do view setup here.

    [[self textField] becomeFirstResponder];  //I tried here...
}

//And overriding initWithNibName:bundle: and setting it here:
-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {

    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        [[self textField] becomeFirstResponder];
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

The File's Owner of MyView.xib is MyViewController, and here are the File's Owner outlets:

[image]

**Response to answer:**

1) This works for me:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    MyViewController* myViewCtrl = [[MyViewController alloc]
                                   initWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:nil];

    [self setViewCtrl:myViewCtrl];

    [[self window] setContentSize:[[myViewCtrl view] bounds].size];
    [[self window] setContentView:[myViewCtrl view]];


    if ([[myViewCtrl textField] acceptsFirstResponder]) {
        [[[myViewCtrl textField] window] makeFirstResponder:[myViewCtrl textField]];

    }

}
```

3) Yes, I am trying to do the first responder dance for the initial showing of the window, but this doesn't work for me:

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    MyViewController* myViewCtrl = [[MyViewController alloc]
                                   initWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:nil];

    [self setViewCtrl:myViewCtrl];

    [[self window] setContentSize:[[myViewCtrl view] bounds].size];
    [[self window] setContentView:[myViewCtrl view]];

    /*
    if ([myViewCtrl acceptsFirstResponder]) {
        [[[myViewCtrl textField] window] makeFirstResponder:[myViewCtrl textField]];

    }
    */

    [[self window] setInitialFirstResponder:[myViewCtrl textField]];



}
```

The window displays fine, but I have to click on the textfield in order to enter text.  If I use `makeFirstResponder:` instead, then the textfield operates like I want:

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    MyViewController* myViewCtrl = [[MyViewController alloc]
                                   initWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:nil];

    [self setViewCtrl:myViewCtrl];

    [[self window] setContentSize:[[myViewCtrl view] bounds].size];
    [[self window] setContentView:[myViewCtrl view]];

    /*
    if ([[myViewCtrl textField] acceptsFirstResponder]) {
        [[[myViewCtrl textField] window] makeFirstResponder:[myViewCtrl textField]];

    }
    */

    [[self window] makeFirstResponder:[myViewCtrl textField]];



}
```

I found that suggestion at [Apple Developer's Event Handling Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventHandlingBasics/EventHandlingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH5-SW22), section Setting the First Responder.

**Response to comment under answer:**

In my app, if I select MainMenu.xib then uncheck `Visible at Launch`, the code below successfully makes the textfield in the View the First Responder:

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  MyFirstResponderApp
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MyViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property(weak)IBOutlet NSWindow* window;
@property(strong) MyViewController* viewCtrl;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate



- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    MyViewController* myViewCtrl = [[MyViewController alloc]
                                    initWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:nil];


    [self setViewCtrl:myViewCtrl];

    [[self window] setContentSize:[[myViewCtrl view] bounds].size];
    [[self window] setContentView:[myViewCtrl view]];

    [[self window] setInitialFirstResponder:[myViewCtrl textField] ];
    [self.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];

}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}

@end
```

If I create a WindowController (along with a .xib, and delete the window in MainMenu.xib), then it makes the most sense to me to organize the configuration/initialization like this:

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  MyFirstResponderApp
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MyViewController.h"
#import "MyWindowController.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property(strong) MyWindowController* windowCtrl;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate



- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    [self setWindowCtrl:[[MyWindowController alloc]
                         initWithWindowNibName:@"MyWindow"]];

}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}

@end
```

Then setup the View by overriding `initWithWindowNibName`in the WindowController:

```
//
//  MyWindowController.h
//  MyFirstResponderApp
//

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface MyWindowController : NSWindowController

-(instancetype)initWithWindowNibName:(NSString *)windowNibName;

@end
```

...

```
//
//  MyWindowController.m
//  MyFirstResponderApp
//


#import "MyWindowController.h"
#import "MyViewController.h"

@interface MyWindowController ()

@property(strong) MyViewController* viewCtrl;

@end

@implementation MyWindowController

-(id)initWithWindowNibName:(NSString *)windowNibName {

    if (self = [super initWithWindowNibName:windowNibName]) {
        MyViewController* myViewCtrl = [[MyViewController alloc]
                                        initWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:nil];


        [self setViewCtrl:myViewCtrl];

        [[self window] setContentSize:[[myViewCtrl view] bounds].size];
        [[self window] setContentView:[myViewCtrl view]];

        [[self window] setInitialFirstResponder:[myViewCtrl textField] ];

        [self showWindow:self]; //I had to uncheck 'Visible at Launch' for the WindowController's window in the Attributes inspector


    }

    return self;
}
- (void)windowDidLoad {
    [super windowDidLoad];

    // Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window controller's window has been loaded from its nib file.


}

@end
```

...

```
//
//  MyViewController.h
//  MyFirstResponderApp
//

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface MyViewController : NSViewController

@property(weak) IBOutlet NSTextField* textField;

@end
```

Comment: I've read the duplicate questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. You should never call `-becomeFirstResponder` yourself (except to call through to super in an override). It says right in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSResponder/becomeFirstResponder):

   > Never invoke this method directly.

   The method is the system *informing* an object that it's about to become the first responder and giving it a chance to refuse. It doesn't actually make the object the first responder.

   The way to make a view the first responder is to first check that it will accept that status and then tell the window to make it the first responder:

   ```
   if ([self.textField acceptsFirstResponder])
       [self.textField.window makeFirstResponder:self.textField];
   ```
2. You are currently trying to make the text field the first responder during initialization of the containing view's view controller. This is too early. The view can't be in a window at this point. So, it can't be a window's first responder, yet. You should do this after the view has been added to a window.

   That job rightfully belongs in a *window* controller, not a view controller. After all, it's only the window controller which has the overview necessary to decide which of its (possibly many) views should be the first responder. You aren't using a separate window controller in this simple app, so the responsibility would fall to the `AppDelegate` class. (It's effectively acting as the window's controller, given the code you posted.)
3. If this is happening before the window is shown, you should consider setting the window's `initialFirstResponder` rather than forcing a view to be the first responder immediately. The window will make its `initialFirstResponder` the first responder when it is first shown.

   It's better to reserve `-makeFirstResponder:` for programmatically changing the first responder after the window has been shown.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. #1 works for me, but I can't get #3 to work. I posted my code at the bottom of my question.

Comment: In your NIB, the window is marked as Visible at Launch, so it is shown as soon as the NIB is loaded. That happens before `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:`, so setting `initialFirstResponder` there is too late. In a real app, you should typically turn off Visible at Launch and you'd programmatically show the window after configuring it. If you use a window controller (WC), you'd configure the window in `-windowDidLoad`. The code which instantiated the WC would show the window by calling `-showWindow:` on the WC. In this toy app, you can do `[self.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self]` after config.

Comment: Thanks for hanging in there with me.  What about overriding `initWithWindowNibName:` in the WindowController and configuring the View there instead of in `windowDidLoad`?  I posted an example of that at the end of my question.

Comment: You're welcome. I guess it works, but it's not ideal. Normally, `NSWindowController` does not load the NIB during initialization. It just records the NIB name. The NIB is not loaded until something requests the window or calls `-showWindow:`. You are turning lazy loading into eager loading. I'm not sure why. Admittedly, it's fairly likely that the "parent" controller — the thing which instantiated this window controller — will request the window or ask for it to be shown immediately, anyway, so it's not much different. *shrug*

Comment: *I'm not sure why.* lol...because I don't know what I'm doing!  To get lazy loading back, is it as simple as moving `showWindow:` out of `initWithWindowNibName:` (and in this case put it App Delegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`).  The name `windowDidLoad`makes it seem like *that* is too late...but it that is the standard way of doing things, then I'll adopt it.

Comment: Well, you would have to not request the `window` property at all in the initializer to get lazy loading back. Move all of the configuration of the window to `-windowDidLoad`. Yes, it's a good idea to move the call to `-showWindow:` to `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` in the app delegate. The initializer is still an OK place to do initialization that the class needs for an object to be valid/complete. For example, if you have an array instance variable that other methods assume is non-`nil`, you'd instantiate it there.

Comment: *Well, you would have to not request the window property at all in the initializer to get lazy loading back..* Ah, I see.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

setting First Responder immediately during initialization can be ignored. especially for a UI component attatched to View Controller other than Window Controller.
There might be a delay between viewWillAppear() and viewDidAppear().

it can be done with window's initialFirstResponder property, or makeFirstResponder() medthod like...

```
window?.initialFirstResponder = yourVC.yourTextField
//OR
window?.makeFirstResponder(yourVC.yourTextField)
```

(Sorry, My brain and hands have deprecated Objective-C )

FYI, the window property can be accessed various ways in some places.
in your custom VC, it would be:

```
self.yourTextField.window?
//OR
NSApplication.sharedApplication().mainWindow?
```

In your custom WindowController:

```
self.window?
//or
NSApplication.sharedApplication().mainWindow?
```

In your Appdelegate.swif :

```
window? //if you use that default property in the template.

//if you have your custom Window Controller instance 'mainWindowController' :
self.mainWindowController.window?
//if you have a custom VC loaded to custom WC, well, :
self.mainWindowController.yourVC.window?
//OR just use 
NSApplication.sharedApplication().mainWindow?
```

but like I said, it can be ignored during luanching if you set it immediately. So you set it after delay:

```
window?.performSelector(#selector(window?.makeFirstResponder(_:)),
                                  withObject: .yourTextField,
                                  afterDelay:0.5)
```

Depending on where you put this, the dot notations of 'window?' and '.yourTextField' parts should be different.